# MVC mobile android not recognizing as mobile device

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a mobile site with .mobile.cshtml
WIthout putting anything in global.asax iphone works and loads my mobile view.
I saw I may need to add opera mobi.
Do I need to specify every mobile type if they are all going to the same mobile view?
What do I need to do so that it should work for android?

I added code where i manually entered a list of mobile devices .
I would think mvc mobile would have this out of the box.
What am I missing that i need to specify a list of devices.
Just saying ismobiledevice in the global.asax does NOT work
Thank you